# jquery for two events two selectors same function

Tags: event-handling, mouseevent, jquery

I'm trying to create a jquery animation.

The problem is I want the animation to trigger only if two conditions are met. 1. if `(#element1).mouseleave==true and (#element2).mouseleave==true`, then trigger the function.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#contact').add('#rt').mouseenter(function(){
     $('#contact').animate({bottom:'45px'}).add('#rt').animate({marginTop:'555px'});
     });
  if(($('#contact').mouseleave()==true)&& ($('#rt').mouseleave()==true)){
  $('#contact').animate({bottom:'-2px'}).add('#rt').animate({marginTop:'600px'});
}
});
```

the function with mouseenter works right, the issue is with mouseleave event. The function won't trigger. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we see a the markup for this? is `#rt` inside of `#contact`?

Comment: Try mouseout instead of mouseleave

Comment: @Ohgodwhy NO. #rt is outside #contact

Comment: <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="contact">Contact
    </div>
    <div id="rt"><br />
    9876, Beverly Hills, CA 11419
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

Answer (score 0):

What you would need to do is set a mouselave on each element and then when one has mouse leave, check the other to make sure that the cursor position is not over the element and vice versa. If the condition is met then call a function with your animate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#contact').add('#rt').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#contact').animate({bottom:'45px'}).add('#rt').animate({marginTop:'555px'});
    });
    $('#contact').mouseleave(function(){
        $('#contact').animate({bottom:'-2px'}).add('#rt').animate({marginTop:'600px'});
    });
});
```

**OR**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#contact').add('#rt').hover(function(){
        $('#contact').animate({bottom:'45px'}).add('#rt').animate({marginTop:'555px'});
    },function(){
        $('#contact').animate({bottom:'-2px'}).add('#rt').animate({marginTop:'600px'});
    });
});
```

Read [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover)

Comment: Doesn't work. When I use .add() to chain the events,they trigger even when one mouseout occurs. I want the function to trigger only if both are 'mouseout'-ed.